# Sylow 2-subgroups in non-abelian group of order 2012

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order 2012.

I have shown the following:

- $G$ has a unique normal subgroup $S$ of order 503
- $S$ is cyclic and the automorphism group $\textrm{Aut}(S)$ contains an unique element of order 2, namely the one sending $x$ to $x^{-1}$.

  If $H$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$, then $G/S\simeq H$ and $G=SH$.

I am then asked to show that if $G$ is not abelian, then the Sylow 2-subgroups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: @DanielFischer They would have to be $\mathbb{Z}_4$. But where to I go from there?

Comment: @StudentG: you've been asked the impossible. It is perfectly ok for the Sylow 2-subgroups to be cyclic.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I have? Could you provide a counter example?

Comment: Take a semidirect product.

Comment: OK. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: Consider the matrix group defined over the integers mod 503: $$G = \left\langle
\left[
\begin{smallmatrix}
-1 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\right],
\left[
\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 &  0 & 1 \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\right]
\right\rangle
$$

The first generator has order 4 and generates a cyclic Sylow 2-subgroup, the second has order 503 and generates a normal Sylow 503-subgroup.